# influxDB line protocol insert using nifi executeScript

Tags: apache-nifi, influxdb

I am getting an error on writing a script in an attempt to get data into influxDB. The following creates executeScript syntax error which seems to work fine sending the line through the API.

```
test_measurement,inputType=json 
  aID="102185",cType="text",pub="2018-07-24 
  20:17:13Z",fetch="2018-07-24 16:17:23-04:00" 1532541609
```

Inserted the following script in nifi ExecuteScript but it keeps throwing the following error:

```
Failed to process session due to javax.script.ScriptException: <eval> Missing space after numeric literal  line = line + inputType="json" + " " + ",aID="2312321" + ",cType="text" + ",pub="2018-07-24 13:09:12" + ",fetch="2018-07-24 13:20:02" + " " + Date.now() * 1000000;
```

Any help or thoughts please.

Comment: Kinda off topic, NiFi comes with PutInfluxDB processor. Will that not help you with your case?

Comment: I am using that processor but prior to that the json needs to be formatted in order to be inserted into influx

Comment: I think the issue is with the way you have used quote sign, especially in `aID`. If you want to have `2312321` within quotes, you may want to escape them.